# How to use CTE instead of Cursor

Tags: cursor, common-table-expression

I want to use Common Table Expressions (CTE) instead of Cursor in SQL Server 2012. Your assistance is highly appreciated.

This is my situation:

```
DECLARE
@tp_ID INTEGER

truncate table T_Rep_Exit_Checklist_Table

DECLARE cursorName CURSOR -- Declare cursor
LOCAL SCROLL STATIC

FOR

SELECT
tp_ID
from V_Rep_Exit_Checklist

OPEN cursorName -- open the cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM cursorName  INTO @tp_ID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

insert into T_Rep_Exit_Checklist_Table
SELECT
@tp_ID-- AS tp_ID
,Item_Status_Code
,Item_Status_Desc
,Item_Code
,Item_Desc
,Item_Cat_Code
,Item_Cat_Desc
,Item_Cleared_By_No
,Item_Cleared_By_Name
V_Rep_Exit_Checklist c


   FETCH NEXT FROM cursorName
    INTO @tp_ID
END

CLOSE cursorName -- close the cursor

DEALLOCATE cursorName -- Deallocate the cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

Something about your query doesn't seem to make sense. It seems like your INSERT statement with the SELECT is missing a where clause and therefore if you source view have 5 records for instance, you insert 25 records because you take the id of the first record during the first iteration with the cursor, and insert all records with that id, then repeat for each row of the view.

Assuming the above logic is intended, then you should just need a CROSS JOIN:

```
INSERT T_Rep_Exit_Checklist_Table
    SELECT
        T1.tp_ID,
        T2.Item_Status_Code,
        T2.Item_Status_Desc,
        T2.Item_Code,
        T2.Item_Desc,
        T2.Item_Cat_Code,
        T2.Item_Cat_Desc,
        T2.Item_Cleared_By_No,
        T2.Item_Cleared_By_Name 
    FROM V_Rep_Exit_Checklist T1
        CROSS JOIN V_Rep_Exit_Checklist T2
```

However, you would like to see it as CTE:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT * FROM V_Rep_Exit_Checklist
)
INSERT T_Rep_Exit_Checklist_Table
    SELECT
        T1.tp_ID,
        T2.Item_Status_Code,
        T2.Item_Status_Desc,
        T2.Item_Code,
        T2.Item_Desc,
        T2.Item_Cat_Code,
        T2.Item_Cat_Desc,
        T2.Item_Cleared_By_No,
        T2.Item_Cleared_By_Name 
    FROM CTE T1
        CROSS JOIN CTE T2
```

If my assumption is wrong and instead you are trying to just insert all records in the view directly into the table, then why not just a simple INSERT as below?

```
INSERT T_Rep_Exit_Checklist_Table
    SELECT
        tp_ID,
        Item_Status_Code,
        Item_Status_Desc,
        Item_Code,
        Item_Desc,
        Item_Cat_Code,
        Item_Cat_Desc,
        Item_Cleared_By_No,
        Item_Cleared_By_Name 
    FROM V_Rep_Exit_Checklist
```

However, if your business requirement is such that you can only insert the records from your view 1 tp_ID at a time, a while statement could be used to replace your cursor:

```
DECLARE @Records TABLE (tp_ID INT)
INSERT @Records
    SELECT tp_ID FROM V_Rep_Exit_Checklist
DECLARE @tp_ID INTEGER
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Records) BEGIN
    SET @tp_ID = (SELECT TOP 1 tp_ID FROM @Records)
    INSERT T_Rep_Exit_Checklist_Table
        SELECT
            tp_ID,
            Item_Status_Code,
            Item_Status_Desc,
            Item_Code,
            Item_Desc,
            Item_Cat_Code,
            Item_Cat_Desc,
            Item_Cleared_By_No,
            Item_Cleared_By_Name 
        FROM V_Rep_Exit_Checklist
        WHERE tp_ID = @tp_ID
    DELETE @Records WHERE tp_ID = @tp_ID
END
```